# How to create a random topic at run time in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new at Kafka. I am trying to create a random topic name at run time. My producer create a random string like MQ* and it uses that string as topic and send to message that topic.
Consumer side know that random topic and subscribe it. But consumer couldn't poll records. I am getting below error producer or consumer side.

```
WARN 10816 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {MQ654498631=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
```

Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Do your brokers allow to create topics automatically? Check broker config's option `auto.create.topics.enable`. It should be `true`

Answer (score 0):

Set auto.create.topics.enable to true in the broker's config.